# Java .split() with a "complex" regex

Tags: java, regex, split

Im trying to split strings like the following :

`"a||b && c || true||false"` into the following array: `{a,||,b,&&,c,||,true,||,false}`

Which means that that I want to sepharate each component with the `|| &&` delimiters ( they can appear anywhere in the string)

*Note that anything can appear between the `|| &&` delimiters. it doesn't really matter to me.

note that white spaces can appear in the string but should be ignored when the string is split into an array.

I didn't manage to find a regex / way to do it, would glad to get help in this subject, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think you cann't spit it with one regex because in your input '**a||b && c || true||false**' is nothing between **a** and **||** to split:

- *a||b* -> nothing to split with
- *true||false* -> nothing to split with

An easy solution is to add a seperator char befor and after the logical operaors:

```
string.replaceAll(Pattern.quote("||"), ",||,")
                    .replaceAll(Pattern.quote("&&"), ",&&,");
```

To remove all whitespaces you can replace them with a empty String:

```
string.replaceAll("\\s", "");
```

You can split your prepared String with your seperator char:

```
String[] splitted = preparedString.split(",");
```

Complete solution:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        String string = "a||b && c || true||false";

        String preparedString = string.replaceAll(Pattern.quote("||"), ",||,")
                .replaceAll(Pattern.quote("&&"), ",&&,")
                .replaceAll("\\s", "");

        String[] splitted = preparedString.split(",");

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(splitted));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[a, ||, b, &&, c, ||, true, ||, false]
```